# Share wired internet connection of windows 7 pc to iPad via bluetooth?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, internet-connection, connection-sharing

At my work, we have wireless... but our desktops are wired.
The wireless in the building is sparse and horrible and my iPad has an unstable wifi connection to it.

However, I was wondering since my iPhone is capable of sharing internet to my iPad via bluetooth protocol, if my PC could somehow reproduce that same protocol and allow the iPad to do the same?

I'd love it if my iPad had a stable connection via bluetooth when it's just sitting near my desktop.

Please advise!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about bluetooth internet sharing. It would be easier to buy a cheap Wi-Fi dongle (TP-Link TL-WN722N is 13USD in amazon.com) and use the software [connectify.me](http://www.connectify.me) to setup your personal hot-spot at your desk. Would be much faster than bluetooth protocol.